# Trouble constructing a function properly in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop

In the code below, I'm trying to find the mean correct score for each item in the "category" column of the "regular season" dataset I'm working with.

```
rs_category <- list2env(split(regular_season, regular_season$category), 
        .GlobalEnv)
unique_categories <- unique(regular_season$category)

for (i in unique_categories)
  Mean_[i] <- mean(regular_season$correct[regular_season$category == i], na.rm = TRUE, .groups = 'drop')
  eapply(rs_category, Mean_[i])
print(i)
```

I'm having trouble getting this to work though. I have created a list of the items in the category as sub-datasets and separately, (I think) I have created a vector of the unique items in the category in order to run the for loop with. I have a feeling the problem may be with how I defined the mean function because an error occurs at the "eapply()" line and tells me "Mean_[i]" is not a function, but I can't think of how else to define the function. If someone could help, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue would be that `Mean_` wouldn't have an `i` name.  In the below code, we initiaize the object 'Mean_' as type `numeric` with `length` as the same as length of 'unique_categories', then loop over the sequence of 'unique_categories', get the subset of 'correct', apply the `mean` function and store that as `i`th value of 'Mean_'

```
Mean_ <- numeric(length(unique_categories))
for(i in seq_along(unique_categories)) {
      Mean_[i] <- mean(regular_season$correct[regular_season$category 
                           == unique_categories[i]], na.rm = TRUE)
   }
```

---

If we need to use a faster execution, use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(regular_season[,  .(Mean_ = mean(correct, na.rm = TRUE)), category]
```

---

Or using `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
fmean(slt(regular_season, category, correct), g = category)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of splitting the dataset and using `for` loop R has functions for such grouping operations which I think can be used here. You can apply a function for each unique group (value).

```
library(dplyr)

regular_season %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  summarise(Mean_ = mean(correct, na.rm = TRUE)) -> result
```

This gives you average value of `correct` for each `category`, where `result$Mean_` is the vector that you are looking for.

In base R, this can be solved with `aggregate`.

```
result <- aggregate(correct~category, regular_season, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```